# how to write a code in solidity that round up instead of down in divisions?

Tags: math, solidity, smartcontracts, division

I need a code that rounds up in case of a division. for example I need the answer to 5/2 to be 3 (in solidity division the answer is 2).
I can use something like bellow but I was wondering if there is another way (a better way) to do it.

```
if( firstNumber%2 == 0){
    div = firstNumber/secondNumber;
}else{
   div = (firstNumber/secondNumber) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid rounding down you can create a multiplier. For example:

```
uint multiplier = 10
uint x = (5 * multiplier) / 2;
```

So the result would be 25. I don't know if this solution is the best one, since you would have to consider this multiplier in the subsequent operations, but it is one of the solutions to avoid rounding down.

More specifically in your case where you would like a rounding up then it could be done something like this:

```
div = (firstNumber + 1)/ secondNumber
```

Some examples:

```
div = 5 + 1 / 2 = 3
div = 11 + 1 / 3 = 4
div = 15 + 1 / 4 = 4
```

And if the number was divisible this wouldn't create a problem, since solidity itself would round down:

```
div = 4 + 1 / 2 = 2
div = 8 + 1 / 2 = 4
div = 12 + 1 / 3 = 4
```

Maybe more testing is needed, but apparently this solution might work.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
function divisionRoundUp(uint256 x, uint256 y) pure returns (uint256 z) {
  z = (x + (y / 2) / y)
}
```

If you used `z = (x + 1) / y;` then you would get 1/1 = 2

Comment: This implementation is incorrect.  For `x=1` and `y=3` it returns `0` while the correct answer would be `1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
div = firstNumber / secondNumber + (firstNumber % secondNumber == 0 ? 0 : 1);
```